# "Show More" option in TabHost (Android) like in iOs

Tags: java, android, ios

Is there any built-in solution when a TabHost have a high number of tabs and dont fit in the screen like the "More ..." option in iOs?

[image]

Comment: You can read a bit about tabs and recommended approaches here: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android you usually approach this using a horizontalScrollView to hold the tabs, or better yet use a viewpager like the Google+ or Google Play app.

Take a look at http://viewpagerindicator.com/ to see an implementation and a library of this functionality